# Why Youtube videos in FancyBox are not showing when used on mobile devices?

Tags: fancybox

I am using Fancybox to display youtube videos.  In PC and MAC everything works good, but not in mobile devices. The code i have is:

```
  <div class="gallery slider">
        <div><a class="various fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Falltape" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZeStnz5c2GI?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"><img src="../images/2.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="various fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Barn" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/4tS88S6em8Y?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"><img src="../images/1.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="various fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Barn" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/4tS88S6em8Y?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"><img src="../images/2.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="various fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Falltape" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZeStnz5c2GI?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"><img src="../images/2.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="various fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Barn" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/4tS88S6em8Y?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"><img src="../images/1.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="various fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Barn" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/4tS88S6em8Y?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"><img src="../images/2.jpg"></a></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'elastic',
                closeEffect: 'none',
                type: "iframe",
                iframe: {
                    preload: false
                }
            });
        });
```

What can be going on?

When i use Developer Tools the following error is showing:

**Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-shockwave-flash.trong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it.

The issue here was the URL used to access the Youtube videos.  I changed the URLs and now it works:

```
<div class="gallery slider">
        <div><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Falltape" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_bFYdMYG-w?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque"><img src="../images/2.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Barn" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_bFYdMYG-w?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque"><img src="../images/1.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Barn" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_bFYdMYG-w?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque"><img src="../images/2.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Falltape" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_bFYdMYG-w?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque"><img src="../images/2.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Barn" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_bFYdMYG-w?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque"><img src="../images/1.jpg"></a></div>
        <div><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe slick-slide" title="The Barn" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_bFYdMYG-w?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque"><img src="../images/2.jpg"></a></div>
    </div>
```

By reading the YouTube API documentation it is clealy defined that the URL to use must be in the following format:

**https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID**

I was not using that format.